# show results of sql code per month in one view

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, common-table-expression, sql-except

I have this SQL statement that generates the revenue, the total customer and revenue for new business.

I would like to amend my SQL to allow it to show the same result but also run it for the previous 3 years with the same logic.

One option is to use a union and amend every time the current_date with DATEADD function by -1 , -2 etc. But this would be so inefficient.

Is there a better way to amend the code? with a date dimension maybe?

```
select date_trunc('month',current_date),
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN (case when RELEVANT_DATE_OUTBOUND> current_date then TOTAL_REVENUE end)>0 THEN CUSTOMER_NAME end) CUSTOMER_ID,
SUM(CASE WHEN (case when date_trunc('month',reporting_date) = date_trunc('month',current_date) then NB_EUR end)>0 THEN nb_eur end) nb_eur
from REVENUE_DATABASE_AGR_VIEW
```

Please find attached the dataset and result of the SQL and desired outcome.

dataset:  [image]

---

### results: [image]

desired outcome: [image]

Comment: Any chance you can edit the question to change from images of the data to text? It will save time for the people who want to answer, so you'll get more responsiveness. Also, over time as the images break people coming to Stackoverflow won't be able to benefit from the answer if the data in the question is no longer available.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you create a date_dim table and use that to provide the date values to join with your query as the date parameter.

You could also use a loop, but row based processing is pretty non-performant in Snowflake.

However, if you're only running it once to populate the prior 3 years, and then once per day only to do each new day's data, then you could wrap your existing code in a loop like the following to process all the historical data, and then use your query with just the current_date()-1 and run daily prospectively:

```
create
or replace table date_dim (loop_date varchar);

declare ctr number(4, 0);
begin ctr: = 0;
while (ctr <= 1095) do -- create date for prior 3 years
   insert into
       date_dim
   select
       current_date() - :ctr;
   ctr: = ctr + 1;
end while;
end;
```